# Jquery goes back to top after action

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery to jump to another section of my page at click of button. I have used following to that:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#bike").click(function (){

                location.href = "#scrolltohere"; 

            });

        });
    </script>
```

//This is where i click

```
<a href="/Bike" id="bike">Bikes</a>
```

//This is the section i want to jump to

```
<div class="eshop-section section" id="scrolltohere">
<h2 style="font-family: 'Lato'; font-size: 40px;" >&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbspBikes</h2>
```

But the problem is, it scrolls and goes back to top of the page.

What to do in this case?

Comment: 1. make good use of HTML anchor; 2. use a newer version of jQuery please.

Comment: Do you have `URL/Bike` page?

Comment: yes, i have indeed

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to bind event handler to navigate to a section, Use [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) properly

> A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies an internal target location (an ID of an HTML element) within the current document.

```
<a href="#scrolltohere">Bikes</a>
```

```html
<a href="#scrolltohere">Bikes</a>
<div style="min-height:1200px;"></div>
<div id="scrolltohere">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: @Anon, Do you have event handler attached to `anchor` element?

Comment: No just <a href="/Bike" id="bike">Bikes</a>
I'm using laravel btw

Comment: @Anon, You need `<a href="#scrolltohere">Bikes</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault` to prevent the default action of the anchor and you can use animate for a smooth scroll animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bike").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#scrolltohere").offset().top
}, 2000);
  });
});
```

Also, you have to add `;` after each of those `&nbsp` like: `&nbsp;`

See a demonstrative working snippet below please:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bike").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#scrolltohere").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.divider{
  height: 500px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/Bike" id="bike">Bikes</a>
<div class='divider'></div>
<div class="eshop-section section" id="scrolltohere">
<h2 style="font-family: 'Lato'; font-size: 40px;" >&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Bikes</h2>
```

**UPDATE**:

If the element you want to scroll to is on another page then you can remove the `jQuery` code you use for the `click` and simply change the `href` on the `anchor` to:

```
<a href="/Bike#scrolltohere" id="bike">Bikes</a>
```

Comment: @Anon, localhost server can be accesed only by you.

Comment: When it redirects to that? When you click the anchor?

Comment: Yes, after i click on anchor

Comment: @Anon, check the console for errors. Are there any errors? Do you have the jQuery library included?

Comment: @Anon. You did not answer my question regarding the errors. If you have jQuery included correctly, ok. Check my updated answer. Try that please.

Comment: Is there any possibility of this happening because of laravel routes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137531/discussion-between-anon-and-ionut).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bike").click(function() {
    location.href = "#scrolltohere";
    return false; // Block page from navigating away to /Bike
  });
});
```

HTML: Change your div to `<a name="scrolltohere"></a>`

```
<a name="scrolltohere"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#scrolltohere" id="bike">Bikes</a>
```

**Use the  above statement instead of**

```
<a href="/Bike" id="bike">Bikes</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening is when you click `Bikes` link it will fire `$("#bike").click` event, you set `location.href="#scrolltohere"` it will scroll till there but after that, the page will go to `URL/Bikes` because you set `href` attribute for the link you clicked `<a href="/Bike" id="bike">Bikes</a>` 
 so whenever a new page loads it will go to top always.
If you put `e.preventDefault()` the default behavior of anchor tag will not work, that is the page will not redirect to `URL/Bikes`

If your intention is to scroll down to `scrolltohere` div either you set `href` attribute to 
 `<a href="#scrolltohere" id="bike">Bikes</a>`
OR put `e.preventDefault();` inside the `$("#bike").click` click event.

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
// $("#bike").click(function(e) {
//    e.preventDefault();
//    location.href = "#scrolltohere";    
//  });
//});
```

```css
.section {
  margin-top: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#scrolltohere" id="bike">Bikes</a>



<div class="eshop-section section" id="scrolltohere">
  <h2 style="font-family: 'Lato'; font-size: 40px;">
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbspBikes
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what should i do?

Comment: @Anon I updated my answer hope it will help you. Happy coding:D